# tomcat8 on centos server load too slow, have Memory Leak warning

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, tomcat8

my tomcat takes many time to deploy my project in server, if just shut down and start my project it takes 5 minutes , but if I change war files it takes near 30 minutes to deploy and run my project,

I saw this warning in my catalina.out , is it related to slow working of my tomcat?

```
WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [proj] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
```

I put my war files on webapps folder and I use Apache8-0-45

whats the problem with my tomcat? how can make my tomcat faster?
how can I fix this memory leak?

ps: yesterday when I searched I saw on the internet I should put this line in the context.xml and I did . It makes it a little better , at least I guess!

```
<Resources cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="100000" />
```

ps2: I'm new in both using tomcat and server :|

ps3 : I read this[ [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32007753/why-my-tomcat-which-on-centos-is-too-slow-when-i-access-it)] and test it , it's not proxy problem,I think.

ps4: the project is very big and has many queries, so I cant bring them here! unfortunately :/

edit:  this log is in catalina.2017-08-26.log

```
        26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.178 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.180 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.232 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.283 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.759 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.761 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.762 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.762 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.763 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.764 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.765 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.765 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.766 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.767 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.768 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.769 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:253)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.804 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.805 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.805 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.806 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.807 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.808 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.808 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.809 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.810 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:48.811 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project2] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.006 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.007 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.009 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.010 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.012 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.014 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.015 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.016 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.017 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.020 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:568)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.021 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.023 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project4] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:253)
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.050 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.078 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.179 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Aug-2017 11:14:49.180 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.419 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.45
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 26 2017 20:06:07 UTC
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.45.0
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.423 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_144-b01
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.45
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.45
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.45/conf/logging.properties
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.424 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.425 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.425 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.425 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.45/endorsed
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.425 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.45
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.425 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.45
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.425 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.45/temp
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.426 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.622 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.647 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.650 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.653 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Aug-2017 11:15:35.654 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 748 ms
26-Aug-2017 11:15:36.311 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
26-Aug-2017 11:15:36.312 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.45
26-Aug-2017 11:15:36.375 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.45/webapps/project2.war
26-Aug-2017 11:15:47.359 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.validateSecurityRoles Security role name wslogin used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
26-Aug-2017 11:15:47.725 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

Comment: *Stack trace of thread:*... you should share that as well.

Comment: how  can I get stack trace of thread ? with this command : ps aux|grep tomcat ? ( this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735280/how-do-we-generate-stack-trace-in-tomcat?rq=1) )

Comment: there would be a file created by present date in your `logs` folder within CATALINE_HOME

Comment: there where some files by present date which one? , catalina.2017-08-26.log--- host-manager.2017-08-26.log ---   localhost.2017-08-26.log  ---localhost_access_log.2017-08-26.txt ---manager.2017-08-26.log  ;; also I have catalina.out  I found the waning (memory leak warning which I wrote in the question  in catalina.out)

Comment: you might want to look into the stacktrace at the same time in the  `catalina.2017-08-26.log` file

Comment: I found sth and I edit the post :)

Answer (score 0):

> whats the problem with my tomcat?

It's your application.

> how can make my tomcat faster?

There are already some hints in your log file:

> `INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.`

How many JAR files do you have? If you have a large number of them and/or have large JAR files, then Tomcat can take a long time scanning them for annotations, servlet initializers, etc. If you don't use any of that stuff, you can [disable JAR scanning entirely](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html) (`scanClassPath="false"`), and if you know some (especially large) JARs don't have anything worth scanning in them, then you can [blacklist them from JAR scanning](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/jar-scan-filter.html).

Also:

> `WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [project3] appears to have started a thread named [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:`

If you restart your application without restarting Tomcat, those threads probably continue to live forever. After a couple of reloads, you have many many threads just churning-away at your CPU (possibly... it depends upon whether those threads actually wake and accomplish something useful after the redeploy).

> how can I fix this memory leak?

Ensure that Quartz is cleanly shut-down when your application is shutting down.